# Is the dimension of an immersed manifold unique?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $F:M^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be an immersion between two manifolds which is not necessarily injective. Denote the immersed manifold by $S = F(M^n)$, we are tempted to say that $S$ has dimension $n$. However is it possible that there exists a second immersion $G:\tilde{M}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $G(\tilde{M}^{n+1}) \subset S$? We are assuming that all manifolds are second countable.

Comment: An immersion is a local embedding.  So, away from singular points due to global self-intersections, the dimension is the same as the dimension of the tangent space (which is invariant under an inversion).

Comment: That's right, however the seemingly hard part is to prove that there can't be an uncountable many of self-intersections such that near such intersections the manifold can also be described as locally $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Comment: If that were to happen, then every point in the image would have uncountably many preimages in $M$.  This would likely break second-countability (but I haven't checked the details).

Comment: That's also the route I had in mind, however I can't see why the preimages (presumably the preimages of a set of the form $G(U)$ with $U \subset \tilde{M}^{n+1}$ open)  have open neighborhoods in $M^n$? Already thanks for your help.

Comment: Even more is true: If $F: M^n\to R^m$ is a locally injective continuous mapping, then $F(M)$ cannot equal the image of a locally injective continuous mapping $G: N^{n+1}\to R^m$. To prove it, use the Baire Category Theorem (represent $G^{-1}(F(M))$ as a countable union of closed nowhere dense subsets).

Comment: Thank you @MoisheCohen, this seems promising. Could you maybe give some details on how to check the conditions in Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: @abcdef: OK....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K^k, M^m, N^n$ be topological manifolds of dimensions $k, m, n$ respectively, such that $k< m$. (All my manifolds are 2nd countable.) Actually, it suffices to assume that $N$ is a Hausdorff topological space, I will not need it to be a manifold.

Suppose that 
$$
f: K\to N, g: M\to N
$$ 
are locally injective continuous maps.

**Proposition.** The image of $f$ cannot contain the image of $g$.

Proof. Since $f$ is locally injective and $K$ is 2nd countable, there exists a countable cover $\{U_i: i\in I\}$ of $K$ such that $f|_{cl(U_i)}$ is 1-1 (hence, a homeomorphism to its image) for each $i$. Similarly, we have a countable cover $\{V_j: j\in J\}$ of $M$ such that $g|_{cl(V_j)}$ is 1-1 for each $j$. For each $i\in I, j\in J$ consider the compact subset
$$
L_{ij}= cl(V_j)\cap g^{-1}( f(cl(U_i))\subset M. 
$$
This subset is homeomorphic to a compact subset of $K$ (via a composition of the restriction of $g$ to $cl(V_j)$ followed by the inverse to $f|_{cl(U_i)}$). Hence, since $dim(K)< dim(M)$, by the invariance of domain theorem $L_{ij}$ has empty interior in $M$. (Here the proof is easier in the smooth setting since $L_{ij}\subset M$ is then diffeomorphic to a compact subset of $K$.) It follows that
$$
X:=\bigcup_{i\in I, j\in J} L_{ij}
$$
has empty interior in $M$ by the Baire Category Theorem. In particular,  $g^{-1}(f(K))\ne M$, hence, $g(M)$ is not contained in $f(K)$.  qed

Comment: Thank you very much. I will likely accept this answer, after I've checked the details. I would like to ask if you have a reference for this 'Theorem'? If not, how did you got the idea to use the Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: @abcdef I do not know a name/reference of this result. The Baire category is a very standard tool in topology. I saw a similar argument in the theory of topological transformation groups (Arens Theorem).

Answer (score 1):

Let $F:M^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be an immersion and assume that $m>n$.  Suppose that there is some point $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ such that 
$$
\bigcup_{x\in F^{-1}(y)}dF_x(T_xM)
$$
is a subspace of $T_yN$ of dimension (strictly) greater than $n$.  This implies that $x\in F^{-1}(y)$ has an uncountable number of points.

If $F^{-1}(y)$ is discrete, this contradicts second-countability.  If $F^{-1}(y)$ is not discrete, then it contains a limit point $x_0$.  But then $F$ is not an immersion since, at $x_0$, $F$ is not locally injective.  This is a contradiction.

If $G$ were an immersion whose image is included in the image of $F$, then suppose that $G(z)=y$ for some $y\in F(M)$.  Since $G$ is an immersion, $dG_z$ is injective and the tangent space is $n+1$-dimensional.  This means that you have $n+1$ independent "directions" that you can travel.  On the other hand, the union above includes at most countably many $n$-dimensional directions.  This is fewer than for $G(z)$, which shows that you can travel in a direction that remains in the image of $G$, but not in the image of $F$.

You can make this discussion of directions rigorous by identifying tangent vectors with curves through a point in your manifold.

Comment: Thank you, I get your idea. However how does this rule out the existence of $G: \tilde{M}^{n+1} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: Edited to give the idea of what you're asking.

Comment: But a curve in $F(M)$ can only be defined by the image of a curve in $M$ or in $\tilde{M}$. I think the difficulty of the problem lies in proving that a curve $G \circ \alpha$ can also be parametrized as $F \circ \beta$ for curves $\alpha$ in $\tilde{M}$ and $\beta$ in $M$. You use this by identifying the tangent spaces induced by $F$ and $G$.

Comment: I think that the way to deal with what you're describing is that you can't have curves jumping between local components of $F(M)$ because there are only countably many local components.  Therefore, curves in $F(M)$ are only images of curves in $M$.

Comment: I suggest you think through this argument under the assumption that both $F$ and $G$ are injective immersions. Can you make it work without hand-waiving? @abcdef

Comment: Oh thank you, yeah it works! I thought I had accepted it already, my bad. But really thanks for helping me!

Comment: @MoisheCohen Was your suggested pointed to me or to abcdef ?  Did you want me to make this more rigorous to improve the answer or as an exercise to abcdef ?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: It was directed to either one of you. It seems (from his/her comment) that abcdef already knows how to do this exercise though.